# Im trying login a website with requests in python

Tags: python, authentication, web, python-requests

I'm trying to login to my coingecko account, but it says the login is wrong even though my account information is correct.
I tried updating the header etc. but it doesn't work

Here is my code:

```py
import time
import requests
import json

s = requests.session()
r = s.get("https://www.coingecko.com/accounts/csrf_meta.json")
token = r.json()["token"]
cookie2 = s.cookies.get_dict()
cookie2 = json.dumps(cookie2)
cookie2 = json.loads(cookie2)
cookie3 = cookie2["_session_id"]

cookie = {
    "_session_id":f"{cookie3}"
}
data = {
    "utf8": "✓",
    "authenticity_token": token,
    "user[email]": "my mail",
    "user[password]": "my passw",
}

r2 = s.post("https://www.coingecko.com/account/sign_in?locale=tr",json=data,cookies=cookie)
print(r2.text)
print(s.cookies.get_dict())
```

It gives me `5B%5B%22alert%22%2C%22Invalid+Email+or+password.%22%5D%5D` cookie value, But my password & Email are true

Comment: if you use `Session` then it should automatically use cookies from previous request and you don't have to do it on your own.

Comment: are you sure it sends data as `json`? Maybe it sends data as normal `form` and this needs `data=...` instead of `json=...`

Comment: how should i use it? one minute ı get a screenshot

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/w4kRVgw.png

Comment: I visited this page and at the bottom is link [Developer API](https://www.coingecko.com/pl/api) and you should use API to get access. There is also link to special Python module [pycoingecko](https://github.com/man-c/pycoingecko)

Comment: but ı cant login with this api and get my access token

Comment: your image shows text `Form-Data` so it suggests that it send it as normal `form`, not `json` and you should use `post(..., data=data)` instead of `post(..., json=data)`

Answer (score 0):

You send it as `JSON` (`json=...`) but have to send it as normal `form` (`data=...`)

```
s.post(url, data=data)
```

---

Minimal working code with other changes.

I used `locale=en` to get flash message in English - and it shows me `Signed in successfully.`

Because you use `Session` so you don't need add `cookies=...` because `Session` should do it automatically.

```
import requests
import json
import urllib

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get("https://www.coingecko.com/accounts/csrf_meta.json")

token = r.json()["token"]

data = {
    "utf8": "✓",
    "authenticity_token": token,
    "user[email]": "my_email",
    "user[password]": "my_password",
    #"user[redirect_to]": "https://www.coingecko.com/en",
    #"user[remember_me]": ["0"]
}

r = s.post("https://www.coingecko.com/account/sign_in?locale=en", data=data)
#print(r.text)

cookies = s.cookies.get_dict() 
print('cookies:', cookies)

if 'flash' in cookies:
    flash = cookies['flash']
    flash = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(flash)
    flash = json.loads(flash)
    print('flash:', flash[0][1])
```

Result:

```
cookies: {'flash': '%5B%5B%22notice%22%2C%22Signed+in+successfully.%22%5D%5D', '_session_id': '0c457f737330527a1eae7f98b0e8df5e'}

flash: Signed in successfully.
```